# Sql query select all messages from everybody inside every group where this one user is at

Tags: sql, select, phpmyadmin, inner-join

I'm trying to get all of the messages, from EVERY user, from 2 groups, where the user is located. But I don't know how to get all message from every group. This is my code so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.*
FROM `message` m 
INNER JOIN users u
ON u.id = m.idUser
LEFT JOIN whats_app w
ON w.idUser= u.id 
WHERE u.id = w.idUser
```

So there is ONLY ONE user in 2 groups. I wan't to get all messages from everybody inside the groups where the ONE user is located at.

this is some simple sql query als example:

```
    create table users (
id                  int         PRIMARY KEY         NOT NULL,
name                varchar(60)
);

create table whatsapp(
idUser              ,
idGroup             int
);

create table allGroups(
id                  int         PRIMARY KEY         NOT NULL,
name                varchar(60)
);

create table message_send(
id                  int,
idUser              int,
message             text
);

INSERT INTO users(id, name) VALUES
(1, 'John'),
(2, 'Martijn'),
(3, 'Rick'),
(4, 'Vera'),
(5, 'Leon');

INSERT INTO allGroups(id, name) VALUES
(1, 'School'),
(2, 'Friends'),
(3, 'moreFriends'),
(4, 'secretmeeting');

INSERT INTO message_send(id, idUser, message) VALUES
(1, 2, 'How are you feeling today?'),
(2, 1, 'What up?'),
(3, 4, 'I am fine, you?'),
(4, 1, 'hi!');
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is you want to get all user of one district and then get all districts these users are?

Comment: Whats your expected output? Question is not clear.

Comment: hmm, i hoped to see every message as output. But when I already put the groupname inside the message_send table, then it will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table message_send(
id                  int,
idUser              int,
idGroup             int,
message             text
);
```

Create message table like this and then just directly join with user and group you will get the output there is not need for the table watsapp

```
select  b.name,message 
from 
message_send as a,
users as b
where
a.idUser=b.id
```

Similarly  join the  group table